# How to Write Unit Test for Racing Condition for Django Using Python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, race-condition

I've implemented an API based on Django and Django REST framework and found it had some problems when it's work under great concurrency.

So I was interested in write some Testing code to reproducing the problem, and improve the code to get it to thread safe later.

I've tried the library `before_after`, and it's quite hard to use if the busy part of the code is not a function or is a function but contains arguments.

I've also tried using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to generate a racing condition, but it raises `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object with alias 'default' was created in thread id 4328317000 and this is thread id 4690485864.`

My implementation is like this:

```
class TestOrderViewSet(APILiveServerTestCase, AuthRequestMixin):

    def test_replace_order_thread_safety(self):
        john_balance = self.john.wallet.balance
        jane_balance = self.jane.wallet.balance
        order_user_pairs = [(mommy.make_recipe('payments.tests.jane_order'), self.jane)]
        for i in range(10):
            order_user_pairs.append((mommy.make_recipe('payments.tests.jane_order'), self.jane))
            order_user_pairs.append((mommy.make_recipe('payments.tests.john_order'), self.john))
        random.shuffle(order_user_pairs)
        print(order_user_pairs)
        self.assertGreaterEqual(Order.objects.count(), 20)

        def replace_order(order, user, i):
            print(i, order.id)
            response = self.auth_post('order', {'pk': order.id}, user)
            print(i, user.wallet.balance)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            user.wallet.refresh_from_db()
            print(i, user.wallet.balance)

        def count_done():
            return sum(int(r.done()) for r in results)

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
            results = []
            for i in range(10):
                r = e.submit(replace_order, *order_user_pairs[i], i)
                results.append(r)
                r = e.submit(replace_order, *order_user_pairs[i], i)
                results.append(r)

            print('done', count_done())
        # e.shutdown(wait=True)
        print('done', count_done())

        self.john.wallet.refresh_from_db()
        self.jane.wallet.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(self.john.wallet.balance, john_balance + 1)
        self.assertEqual(self.jane.wallet.balance, jane_balance - 1)
```

Any kind of suggestions is appreciated. Thanks in advance.